# How to convert case class to HList than to modify than to create case class again by shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Hello I am new in shapeless, I want to create Hlist from case class, than to modify fields than to create case class again, its possible by shapeless:

```
        val user:RfModelCalibration = users.head
        val transformer  = Generic[RfModelCalibration]
        val beforeTransform = transformer.to(user)
        val afterTransform = beforeTransform.map(enumTransform)
        val newCaseClass = transformer.from(afterTransform)
```

But I can't exec "beforeTransform.map(enumTransform)" Can I do It by shapeless?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The following code should compile:

```
  import shapeless.{Generic, Poly1}

  case class RfModelCalibration(field1: Field1, field2: Field2)

  val user: RfModelCalibration = users.head
  val transformer  = Generic[RfModelCalibration]
  val beforeTransform = transformer.to(user)
  val afterTransform = beforeTransform.map(enumTransform)
  val newCaseClass = transformer.from(afterTransform)

  object enumTransform extends Poly1 {
    implicit val cse1: Case.Aux[Field1, Field1] = at(x => ???)
    implicit val cse2: Case.Aux[Field2, Field2] = at(x => ???)
  }
```